# Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 100

Tags: curve-fitting

I'm new to python, I try to give some adjustment to the data, but when I get the graph, only the original data appears and with the message "Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000." Could you help me find my mistake?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as m
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as num
import scipy.optimize as optimize


xData=num.array([0,0,100,200,250,300,400], dtype="float")
yData=num.array([0,0,0,0,75,100,100], dtype="float")

m.plot(xData, yData, 'ro', label='Datos originales')

def fun(x, a, b):
  return a + b * num.log(x)

popt,pcov=optimize.curve_fit(fun, xData, yData,p0=[1,1], maxfev=1000)
print=popt

x=num.linspace(1,400,7)

m.plot(x,fun(x, *popt), label='Función ajustada')

m.xlabel('concentración')
m.ylabel('% mortalidad')
m.legend()
m.grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

The model in your code is "a + b * num.log(x)". Because your data contains an x value of 0.0, the evaluation of log(0.0) gives errors and will not allow the fitting software to function. Sometimes these x values of 0.0 can be replaced with very small numbers, as log(small number) will not fail - but in this case the equation and data do not appear to match and so using that technique alone would not be sufficient here.

My thought is that a different equation would be a better model for this data. I performed an equation search using your data, and found that several different sigmoidal type equations gave suspiciously good fits to this data set - which is not surprising because of the small number of data points.

The sigmoidal equations I tried were all extremely sensitive to the initial parameter estimates. Here is a graphical Python fitter using scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to determine the initial parameter estimates for curve_fit's non-linear solver. That scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. Here those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimun values.

I personally would not use this fit precisely *because* the small number of data points is giving such suspiciously good fits, and strongly recommend taking additional data points if at all possible. I could however not find any equations with less than three parameters that would fit the data.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData=numpy.array([0,0,100,200,250,300,400], dtype="float")
yData=numpy.array([0,0,0,0,75,100,100], dtype="float")


def func(x, a, b, c): # Sigmoid B equation from zunzun.com
    return  a / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-1.0 * (x - b) / c))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 2.0]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData), 100)
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: for this equation, the first fitted parameter is the sigmoid upper asymptote and the second fitted parameter is the "x" midpoint for the low-to-high transition.